# Get matching part from conditional pattern

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, string-searching, string-manipulation

I'm having a table like this:

```
|id|key    |value      |
------------------------
| 0|name   |Homer      |
| 1|surname|Simpson    |
| 2|town   |Springfield|
```

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Search
WHERE [value] LIKE '%m%'
OR [value] like '%p%'
```

Is there any chance to know, which of both conditions did match?

Within **one** statement (so *not* running each of condition separately).

So for example a result like this:

```
|id|key    |value      |match  | 
--------------------------------
| 0|name   |Homer      |%m%    |
| 1|surname|Simpson    |%m%,%p%|
| 2|town   |Springfield|%p%    |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc0b1/3/0

**EDIT:**
The result may also be like this:

```
|id|key    |value      |match  | 
--------------------------------
| 0|name   |Homer      |%m%    |
| 1|surname|Simpson    |%m%    |
| 1|surname|Simpson    |%p%    |
| 2|town   |Springfield|%p%    |
```

**EDIT 2:**
Conditions might be more than two so a generic approach (if possible) would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT value AS pattern            -- or TRIM(value)
         FROM STRING_SPLIT('%m%,%p%', ',')  -- comma is NOT allowed in a pattern
                                            -- or alter your delimiter
       )
SELECT Search.[id], 
       Search.[key], 
       Search.[value], 
       STRING_AGG(cte.pattern, ',') [match]
FROM Search, 
JOIN cte ON Search.[value] LIKE cte.pattern -- or LEFT JOIN
GROUP BY Search.[id], 
         Search.[key], 
         Search.[value]
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c26f3c1990aa4ae2a81b353b7ada9645)

Possibe CTE replace usable on previous server versions (`CHAR(9)` is used as a delimiter, `@pattern` declared before cte must be query parameter transferred from client as literal):

```
DECLARE @pattern VARCHAR(64) = '%m%'+CHAR(9)+'%p%';

WITH cte AS ( SELECT LEFT(@pattern,CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),@pattern)-1) pattern, 
                     SUBSTRING(@pattern, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),@pattern)+1, LEN(@pattern)) slack
              UNION ALL
              SELECT LEFT(slack,CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),slack)-1), 
                     SUBSTRING(slack, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),slack)+1, LEN(slack))
              FROM cte
              WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),slack) > 0
              UNION ALL
              SELECT slack, ''
              FROM cte
              WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),slack) = 0
                AND slack != ''
            )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=05afd3786e2a1f5ec86c2313537e5a49)

STRING_AGG() must be replaced too...

Comment: nice solution but pretty hand tailored

Comment: @ Akina sorry, wasn't meant to be  criticism in any way. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @sc911 Automated. SQL Server 2017 or higher needed.

Comment: wow! thats great! replacing the cte select statement with the following makes it run on SQL 2014 and allows comma in pattern: SELECT *  FROM (VALUES('%m%'),('%p%')) t(pattern)

Comment: @sc911 Using VALUES case to undefined parameters count. One literal which contain all patterns is more usable. I'd recommend to concat patterns on the client side using some predefined delimiter which can not be a pattern part (CHAR(0) for example) and parse this literal in recursive CTE.

Comment: @sc911 Look on CTE variant safe for previous server versions.

Answer (score 0):

Found one by my self:

```
SELECT *, '%m%' AS Pattern
FROM Search
WHERE [value] LIKE '%m%'
UNION 
SELECT *, '%p%' AS Pattern
FROM Search
WHERE [value] like '%p%'
```

But also kind of hand tailored to a fixed set of conditions.